# OnTokenValidated not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add a custom JWT validation on my API layer. I'm using Asp.net core 7.0

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the OnTokenValdate called every time the client requests a method on the API decorated with [Authorize]

The code below works on asp.net net core 3.1. When migration to 7.0 nothing happens.
Below is the code in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

var secretKey = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Auth:SecretKey");


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
               .AddJwtBearer(x =>
               {
                   x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                   x.SaveToken = true;
                   x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey)),
                       ValidateIssuer = false,
                       ValidateAudience = false,
                   };
                   x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                   {
                       OnTokenValidated = context =>
                       {
                           var sessionManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISessionManager>();
                        
                           if (!sessionManager.IsCurrentTokenValid())
                           {
                               context.Fail($"invalidToken");
                            
                           }

                           return Task.CompletedTask;
                       }
                   };
               });

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: OnTokenValidated  would only be called when the claims in your token have been validated successfully,you have to make sure the claims have been validated first

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I created a token without Issuer and Audience and Expires time. So I added **OnAuthenticationFailed** and set a **break point** on it and read the error **message** on AuthenticationFailedContext context. So then I added these options :
ValidateIssuer = false,
ValidateAudience = false,
RequireExpirationTime=false,

```
public static class TokenConfig
{
    public static void AddJwt(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "n";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "r";

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                RequireExpirationTime=false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.JwtSecretKey)),
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                { // set break point here
                    var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TokenValidatorService>();
                    return tokenValidatorService.ValidateAsync2(context);
                },
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TokenValidatorService>();
                    return tokenValidatorService.ValidateAsync(context);
                },
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            };
        });
    }
}
```